# xcodebuid: is there a way to pass a code sign certificate without putting it in the keychain?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ipa, xcodebuild

Automate the Assembly of ios applications. Certificates, provisioning files and other parameters are obtained from an external source. With Assembly now such a trouble.

1. Certificates should be placed in the keychain.
2. At the end of xcodebuild -archive (or xcodebuild -exportArchive), a dialog appears asking permission to access the keychain with the need to enter the administrator password.

Is there a way to avoid these two problems and somehow pass xcodebuild certificates and provisioning profiles parametrically? Need to get a seamless Assembly.

```
xcodebuild archive \
     -project ./FooBar.xcodeproj \
     -scheme FooBar \
     -destination generic/platform=iOS \
     -archivePath ./FooBar.xcarchive \
     IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0 \
     TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY="1" \
     DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=XXXXXXXXXX \
     CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS=FooBar.entitlements

xcodebuild -exportArchive \
     -archivePath ./FooBar.xcarchive \
     -exportPath ./ \
     -exportOptionsPlist ./FooBarExport.plist
```

Certificates come in p12 format with passwords to them.
The option

```
-allowProvisioningUpdates
```

cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are no possibility to pass certificate to xcodebuild. But you can use 
`security` to add certificate to keychain.

```
security add-certificate -k keychain certificate.file
```

And then make

```
security unlock-keychain -p password keychain
```